# Como copio en local o en mi servidor la informacion de una API?

Tags: javascript, api, fetch

Cree una app que sirve los datos de la api de https://ygoprodeck.com/api-guide/ y al poner el nombre de la carta sale la imagen pero creo que excedi las solicitudes y en la guia dice

"NOTE ON IMAGES: Do not continually hotlink images directly from this site. Please download and re-host the images yourself. " y tambien dice que copie la informacion de la api para evitar llamadas innecesarias pero quiro saber como hacerlo?

este es el link de la app https://aguilar.digital/react-work/
y solo quiero saber como copiar la api para consumirla de mi propio serve o algo asi

Comment: Y el server en que está hecho?

Comment: no se mucho de backend pero creo que en PHP por que la api es https://db.ygoprodeck.com/api/v7/cardinfo.php

Comment: Me refiero a tu servidor, no al de la API. O no tienes backend en tu aplicación?

Comment: ooh ya lo siento, pues supongo que es nodeJS por que uso React para desplegar la app en mi hosting en namecheap  como te digo de backend no se casi nada

Comment: Deberías buscar si existe algún repositorio con las imágenes de alguien que ya las haya bajado, copiarlas y ponerlas en tu hosting. La otra manera es que tu tengas una aplicación en tu hosting, para esto deberás ver que lenguaje soporta tu hosting. Entonces, tu aplicación react le pide la imagen a tu aplicación en el servidor, el servidor busca la imagen en el disco, si la encuentra se la pasa, en caso contrario, la va a buscar a la API, la baja y la guarda, para luego entregarla, así la próxima vez ya la tiene guardada. Como se hace esto? Depende del lenguaje que elijas